# Correctly applying logarithm properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

A telescoping series simplifies to the following:

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \ln6-\ln{k}-\ln{(k+1)}-\ln{(k+2}).$$

Analyzing said series, it's known that it diverges: the partial sums go towards $-\infty$.

One also gets this answer from the above simplification,
the subtraend logarithms become $\infty$ and all makes sense.
BUT when I restate the expression using some combinations
of logarithm identities it becomes $\infty$.

For example, after applying the difference in logarithms property twice, from left-to-right
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \ln6-\ln\frac{k}{(k+1)(k+2)} =  \ln6-\ln0 = \ln6-(-\infty) = \ln6 + \infty.$$

There seems to be something about logarithm identities that I don't understand,
e.g. the sign and/or when you have 3 in a row like this.

Why is this changing the sign of the expression?

Comment: Why not just write $$ \log(6) - \log(k) - \log(k+1) - \log(k+1) = \log\left( \frac{6}{k(k+1)(k+2)}\right)?$$  As $k\to \infty$, the argument of the logarithm goes to zero, and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \log(x) = -\infty$, no?

Comment: Also, there is an error in your simplification:  $-\log(k) = \log(1/k)$, not $\log(k)$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I didn't realize it's an error to apply the difference in logarithms property with a minuend logarithm
that's also a subtraend in a larger expression *without treating it as having a negative coefficient or its

argument being raised to a negative exponent*.

$$ c-\log{(k)}-\log{(k+1)} \quad \text{referring to $\log{(k)}$ in above paragraph} $$

Specifically this is how $\log(k)$ is to be treated when applying the difference property
*because it is a subtraend*:

$$ -1\cdot\log(k) = \log(k^{-1}) = \log(1/k),\quad \text{ not } \log(k).$$

In context of the original problem, combining logarithms will yield the expected result of
$-\infty$ when correcting for this. So I was applying the
difference property using an incorrect logarithm, explaining
why in some combinations of restatements, the expression
became what I expected and for others not so.